# Dealing with new fields with Mongo Spring data

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I have a Mongo db running behind a Spring boot application. I'm using the spring boot starter:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

I have existing documents and would like to add a new int field.

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class AlbumKey {

    @Id
    String id;

    SomeObject existingField

    int newField //Doesn't exist yet on the DB for older documents
```

How do I go about adding a default value? If the new field were an object I gather it would be `null`.

Is it as simple as declaring:

```
    int newField = DEFAULT_VALUE;
```

Would it work the same way if it were an object?

Answer (score 2):

The answer is Yes! If you then save the object the default value will be persisted. This means that you can rely on defaults until the user changes them or you could save the objects in getters to ensure the defaults propagate to the DB. Saving in getters isn't per the HTTP standard though so I recommend the former approach.

Also note that updating any other change to the document will persist the defined defaults too.